# Why use lxc instead of chroot?

Tags: ubuntu, security, sftp, chroot, lxc

One ubuntu server hosts 3 apps all on separate domains.
Each app has its own developers.
App developers belong to linux "sftp" group.
`chroot` allows password sftp access for each app developer.

```
/home/app1/prod
/home/app2/prod
/home/app3/prod
```

In sshd_config

```
Match Group sftp  
  PasswordAuthentication yes
  ChrootDirectory %h
  ForceCommand internal-sftp
  AllowTcpForwarding no
```

Our concern is a programming vulnerability in one app causing problems in the other 2 apps.

Should we use lxc container instead of chroot?  Why?  Will the change to lxc containers be transparent to the app developers?

Comment: The only thing `chroot` does is change the root directory for a process.  It offers no isolation or anything else.

Answer (score 17):

Linux Containers (LXC) are an operating system-level virtualization method for running multiple isolated server installs (containers) on a single control host. LXC does not provide a virtual machine, but rather provides a virtual environment that has its own process and network space. It is similar to a chroot, but offers much more isolation.

Linux containers has several features / advantages:

Advantages:

Better isolation as compared to a chroot (chroot jail).
Low overhead. LXC uses minimal resources in terms of RAM and hard drive space without the overhead of installing a guest OS in a virtual machine ( VMWare / VirtualBox / KVM ) .

Applications and services (servers) run at native speed.

There is support for Linux containers in libvirt .

Linux containers work well with btrfs .

But there is also a downside:

Linux containers run Linux processes on a Linux kernel. This means you can run Linux (Fedora container on an Ubuntu host) but not other operating systems (Not BSD / OSX / Windows).

There are no GUI (graphical) interfaces to configure or manage the containers.

There is a paucity of documentation on how to install and configure a container.
Configuring a container requires a modest technical knowledge and skill (and a large grain of patience).

Comment: which kernel is used inside the LXC ? (the one from the host or the guest one ?)

Comment: A lot of the advantages & disadvantages compare LXC to full virtualization, which is irrelevant to the question asked, and perhaps even misleading.

Comment: @Francesco, with LXC, (and Linux containers in general), there is only one kernel- the host kernel. Some exceptions to this are for example, Docker running on MacOS or Windows, as they use a Linux kernel running in a virtual machine; however, all Linux containers on these platforms are still using the same kernel.